# I would like the int sum to count for me the number of time the function is being recursively called. Where should I place the sum and the output

Tags: c++

I am trying to have some tools to count for me how many times this recursive function was called. So, I initiated the `int sum` and place above the line where the function is called recursively. I also printed a `cout` command to see if this is working. But it looks like my `sum++` does not work properly.

[image]

Comment: Please do not share your code as an image, it is far easier to encase the code in backticks and put it directly into the answer.

Comment: You can define sum as `static int` so it will preserve the value between calls.

Comment: You can use `static int sum = 0;` one variable then associated to the function itself, not to one particular call

Comment: it has a code as a screenshot - should be just text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have done is you are always assigning 0 to sum that's why the output is always same. You can make **sum** as a global variable. Refer to the code below:

```
int sum=0;
int fact(int n)
{   
    if(n==1)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        sum++;
        cout<<"Function is called "<<sum<<" times"<<endl;
        return n*fact(n-1);
    }
}
int main()
{
    int n=4;
    cout<<" This is the factorial of: "<< n << ": "<<fact(n)<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, yeah, you are right. That worked.

Answer (score 1):

Your `sum` variable is a local variable. Every call to the function will get a new variable initialized to 0, independent of the variables of earlier calls. That is not what you want.

For a simple example, a `static` variable will allow you carry the `sum` across function calls, eg:

```cpp
int fact(int n)
{
    static int sum  = 0;
    ...
}
```

In production code, an in/out parameter would usually be preferred instead, eg:

```cpp
int fact(int n, int &sum)
{
    ...
    ++sum;
    return n * fact(n-1, sum);
    ...
}

int sum = 0;
... << fact(n, sum) << ...;
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because every new recursive call, a new sum variable in that scope is defined. you need to make your sum variable consistent over every recursion.

depending on the overall task, you have two solutions:

1. make the variable global
2. add a new param for your function "fact" and give the value of "sum" to the next recursion

Comment: This answer, while helpful, is not yet complete. You should add some code that show how to apply your explanations

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be this:

```
int fact (int n, int sum = 0)
{
  // remove int sum = 0
```

Then later in the function when you call the function recursively, do this:

```
sum = sum + 1; // Better to do ++sum by the way
std::cout << "Function is called " << sum << "times\n";
return n * fact(n - 1, sum);
```

The rest of the program will stay the same.

You can also change `int sum = 0;` to `static int sum = 0;` and everything else will be the same. This will make the variable global so it will not be destroyed between function calls